# table.include.list configuration parameter not working in Debezium Postgres Connector

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am using Debezium Postgres connector to capture changes in postgres tables.

The documentation for this connector
https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/postgresql.html

mentions a configuration parameter

```
table.include.list
```

However when I set the value of this parameter to 'config.abc'. Even after that changes from both tables in config schema (namely abc and def) are getting streamed.

The reason I want to do this is that I want to create 2 separate connectors for each of the 2 tables to split the load and faster change data streaming.

Is this a known issue ? Anyway to overcome this ?

Comment: Could you please share your connector configuration? What Debezium version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

The same problem here (Debezium Version: 1.1.0.Final and postgresql:11.13.0). Below is my configuration:

```
{
  "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
  "transforms.unwrap.delete.handling.mode": "rewrite",
  "slot.name": "debezium_planning",
  "transforms": "unwrap,extractInt",
  "include.schema.changes": "false",
  "decimal.handling.mode": "string",
  "database.schema": "partsmaster",
  "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "false",
  "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
  "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.LongConverter",
  "database.user": "************",
  "database.dbname": "smartng-db",
  "transforms.extractInt.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
  "database.server.name": "ASLog.m3d.smartng-db",
  "database.port": "***********",
  "plugin.name": "pgoutput",
  "column.exclude.list": "create_date, create_user, change_date, change_user",
  "transforms.extractInt.field": "planning_id",
  "database.hostname": "************",
  "database.password": "*************",
  "name": "ASLog.m3d.source-postgres-smartng-planning",
  "transforms.unwrap.add.fields": "op,table,lsn,source.ts_ms",
  "table.include.list": "partsmaster.planning",
  "snapshot.mode": "never"
}
```

A change in another table partsmaster.basic is causing this connector to fail because the attribute planning_id is not available in table partsmaster.basic.

I need separate connectors for each table. table.include.list is not working. Neither table.exclude.list does.

My last resort would be to use a separate Postgres Publication for each connector. But I still hope I can find an immediate configuration solution here or be pointed out at what I am missing. In a previous version I have used table.whitelist without problems.

Solution:

1. create seperate publications to each table:

   CREATE PUBLICATION dbz_planning FOR TABLE partsmaster.planning;
2. drop previous replication slot:

   select pg_drop_replication_slot('debezium_planning');
3. Change your connector configurations:

   {
   "slot.name": "dbz_planning",
   "publication.name": "planning_publication"
   }

et voilà!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please do not use answers to ask questions of your own. Instead, open a new question and, if applicable, reference this one. See also [ask].

Comment: The person who opened the question did not reply to which version he is using and what configuration. In order to reduce the open questions, I have added the information to the same question. It is the same problem. If I should remove the comment let me know.

Comment: Hi, I understand your reasoning. Nevertheless, this is not the way StackOverflow works. An answer should always make an attempt to answer the OP's question (see [answer]). If you have the same question it either is already covered by the existing question or you have additional/new information which makes it a different question. Even if you see the same behavior, whether that means it is the same problem or not is something that only someone who knows the actual answer can determine. Once you have gained sufficient reputation, you can alternatively comment on other people's questions.

Comment: Using separate publications for tables worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

[Debezium documentation](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/postgresql.html#postgresql-deploying-multiple-connectors) says

> Thus, you’ll need a unique publication for each connector, unless the connectors work on same set of tables